# Django filtering on related objects

Tags: python, django

In a 3 way relationship model (let's say Poll->Questions->Choices) I am trying to only show the Polls that have at least 1 question which has at least 2 choices.
If the poll has 50 questions and all those questions have 0 or 1 choice, this poll shouldn't be shown.

What I have so far :

```
polls = Poll.objects.annotate(
    num_questions=Count('question')).filter(
    num_questions__gt=0)
```

This correctly gets me the polls that have questions. But some of them don't even have choices, or less than two, so I don't want to see those polls.

What i've tried so far :

```
polls = Poll.objects.annotate(
        num_questions=Count('question')).filter(
        num_questions__gt=0).filter(
        question__choice_set__gte=1)
```

this prints `"Relation fields do not support nested lookups"`

and

```
polls = Poll.objects.annotate(
    num_questions=Count('question')).filter(
    num_questions__gt=0).annotate(
    num_choices=Count('choice_set')).filter(
    num_choices__gt=1)
```

and this prints : `Cannot resolve keyword 'choice_set' into field. Choices are: id, num_questions, poll_enabled, poll_skippable, poll_title, question`

Now i'm kind of running out of ideas. If anyone already had to do that or simply knows how to do it, i'd gladly accept any help.

Comment: For the second question you probably want to query through question since a poll doesn't have any choices according to your explanation

Comment: How would that look like? I'd get all the questions, loop through them and see if any has 2+ choices, and if so, consider the poll to be valid? I was hoping there was a less "bulldozer" way than this...

Comment: Probably this: `Count('question__choice_set')`

Comment: @Wolph, didn't think of that. Doesn't work tho, prints exactly the same error message. I guess there really aren't any other fields that the ones listed!

Comment: it actually worked with 'question__choice', but it doesn't make any sense as I didn't state any related name anywhere? I am confused...However it's working